# Send mail with python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to send email with python.

In the function server.sendmail, when I replace message by a "example text with double quote", I receive my email with the good message.
Now, when I try to send a file content saved in my "message" variable, I receive a empty mail, but if I print my variable, the content is correct.

Have you an idea ?
Thx !

```py
import smtplib, ssl
import os

smtp_adress = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 465

email_adress = 'xxx@gmail.com'
email_password = 'xxx'

email_receiver = 'xxx@hotmail.fr'

# message
file = open('dl_link', 'r')
line = file.readlines()
file.close()

message = line[0]

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_adress, smtp_port, context=context) as server:
  server.login(email_adress, email_password)
  server.sendmail(email_adress, email_receiver, message)

print(message)
```

Comment: Is the first line of `dl_link` blank?

Comment: Why are you sending just one line of text? Shouldn't you send the file?

Comment: dl_link is not blank, when I print it, the text appears.

Comment: The file just content a single line with a link. It will be faster to copy the link in the text of the email than to download my file

Comment: From the docs for sendmail:

msg may be a string containing characters in the ASCII range, or a byte string. A string is encoded to bytes using the ascii codec, and lone \r and \n characters are converted to \r\n characters. A byte string is not modified.

Is this satisfied?

What happens if you turn your message into a byte string with `str.encode(message)`?

Any french accents in the url you are sending perhaps?

Comment: @GuillemB Hello, thx for your answer. Same result if I use str.encode(message). I also tried .to_string(), then I got an error : 'str' object has no attribute 'to_string'. There is no accents in my URL